# using a variable from one class to another

Tags: android, android-intent

**i want to use a vaiable in the main class from ReveiveSMS.class.
This is my code of ReceiveSMS.class and i want to use messageBody in the main.
Help me how can i do it. thanks**

```
package com.formation.gmaps;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ReceiveSMS  extends BroadcastReceiver
{
 private final String   ACTION_RECEIVE_SMS  = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
 {
 if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_RECEIVE_SMS))
 {
 Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
 if (bundle != null)
 {
 Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

 final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
 for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++)  {  messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);  }  if (messages.length > -1)
 {
 final String messageBody = messages[0].getMessageBody();
 final String phoneNumber = messages[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

 Toast.makeText(context, "Expediteur : " + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 Toast.makeText(context, "Message : " + messageBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



 }
 }
 }

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put `messageBody` in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

In ReceiveSMS class :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("yourPrefs", 0);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("messageBody", messageBody);
editor.commit();
```

In your main class :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("yourPrefs", 0);
String messageBody = prefs.getString("messageBody","defaultValue");
```

Comment: and where i will find the content of messageBody ?

Comment: In your `onReceive` method in the ReceiveSMS class, put messageBody in the editor, then you will be able to access its content everywhere in your app by writing the part for the 'main class'